# Open web link only in external browser

Tags: android, browser

I'd like my app opens some urls. But not all.
Android does not allow to exclude urls(( 
by using `android:pathPattern` or `android:pathPrefix`.

Now for opening urls I use:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(PRIVACY_POLICY_URL));
        browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(browserIntent);
```

I want to open some web links only in external browser.
Is it possible?

Comment: Shortest approach `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(PRIVACY_POLICY_URL)));`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Is it that you only want to open SOME urls and not all? Or all Urls in an external browser and not within app? Please clarify

Answer (score 4):

For opening url in external browser you can use this code

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

and if you want to open link in your application , you can use a webview for it and load the url in it as follow

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```